# Is information lost from black body radiation?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, photons, thermal-radiation, information

If you heat water in a microwave all of the water is heated by a narrow wavelength of photons.  As the water cools it emits different photons of radiation in the form of infrared light.

Can you tell how the water was heated from the cooling process? How many photons and their energy.

Comment: I think the distribution of heat is different from heating in microwave vs., E.g., heating on a stove. In addition, water might be a special case of a *material with memory*, due to the inter-molecular hydrogen bonds. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

In a way the information is in the blackbody radiation: [each photon carries $3.897\pm 2.522$ bits of information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.01162). It is just scrambled.

The important thing here is that water does not have a very good memory. Certainly there are hydrogen bonds producing a complicated microstructure, but the interactions mix up any information with the whole structure [within 100 picoseconds](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10765-009-0698-8). You send the collected works of Shakespeare into the water as microwave pulses, and you get them distributed into the thermal noise degrees of freedom nearly instantly - they are there, but you will not recoverable just as past sounds are not recoverable from the heat in a room.

One should remember that information in this sense is Shannon information - how many bits does it take to describe the state - rather than semantic information - what does it mean? Noise has maximal Shannon information, but is meaningless.

So the heating history is forgotten quickly, and only the temperature matters.